# Who is responsible for pidgin-plugin-pack in Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: pidgin, official-repositories

My Ubuntu 12.04 still has pidgin-plugin-pack package version 2.6.3-2, but the latest one is [2.7.0](https://www.guifications.org/projects/purple-plugin-pack/files)

Who is responsible for this package? How to update from 2.6.3 to 2.7.0 in Ubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the package metadata:

```
$ apt-cache show pidgin-plugin-pack | grep Maintainer
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Felix Geyer <debfx-pkg@fobos.de>
```

As you can see, the current maintainer are the Ubuntu Developers. <del>You can fill a package request at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/purple-plugin-pack/+bugs</del> Someone already reported this: [Upstream release 2.7.0 of purple plugin pack](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/purple-plugin-pack/+bug/943674)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu itself is responsible for that.However you can still add the pidgin PPA to software center from the [Pidgin Website](http://www.pidgin.im/download/ubuntu/).Nothing to worry about really :) .